# Calculate middle color beetwen startColor and EndColor

Tags: c#, colors

Need to get middle color beetwen startColor and endColor.

If startColor is "red", endColor is "green", then need to get yellow.

If startColor is "red", endColor is "yellow", then need to get orange and so on.

i've started from default red(start) and green(end) colors.

i have found some formula, in most cases return right color but not always, so need to calculte right percent step.

As you can see from image additional colors yellow(start) and green(end) makes one more green...

```
        public static string LerpHue(Color min, Color max)
    {
        float t = 0.7F // **percent step, need to calculate somehow...**
        float minHue = min.GetHue() / 255;
        float maxHue = max.GetHue() / 255;

        float scale = maxHue - minHue;

        float curHue = minHue + (scale * t);
        double r, g, b;
        HSVToRGB(curHue, 1.0, 1.0, out r, out g, out b);

        Color color = Color.FromArgb((int)(r * 255), (int)(g * 255), (int)(b * 255));            
        return $"#{color.R.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0')}{color.G.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0')}{color.B.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0')}";
    }

    public static void HSVToRGB(double H, double S, double V, out double R, out double G, out double B)
    {
        if (H == 1.0)            
            H = 0.0;            

        double step = 1.0 / 6.0;
        double vh = H / step;

        int i = (int)System.Math.Floor(vh);

        double f = vh - i;
        double p = V * (1.0 - S);
        double q = V * (1.0 - (S * f));
        double t = V * (1.0 - (S * (1.0 - f)));

        switch (i)
        {
            case 1: { R = q; G = V; B = p; break; }
            case 2: { R = p; G = V; B = t; break; }
            case 3: { R = p; G = q; B = V; break; }
            case 4: { R = t; G = p; B = V; break; }
            case 5: { R = V; G = p; B = q; break; }
            default:{ R = V; G = t; B = p; break; }
        }
    }
```

Help please)

[image]

Comment: Hint: Hues wrap around. I see no part that would notice and allow for that situation..

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GetCalculatedColor()
    {
        var colorRangesCount = MeasureAppearance.GaugeRanges.Count;
        int step = 1;
        var startRange = MeasureAppearance.GaugeRanges.FirstOrDefault();
        var endRange = MeasureAppearance.GaugeRanges.LastOrDefault();
        Color startColor = Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(startRange?.Color.Replace("#", "") ?? "0", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
        Color endColor = Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(endRange?.Color.Replace("#", "") ?? "0", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
        foreach (var gaugeRange in MeasureAppearance.GaugeRanges)
        {
            if (gaugeRange == startRange || gaugeRange == endRange)
                continue;
            var calculatedColor = ColorService.LerpHueReal(startColor, endColor, (1f / (colorRangesCount - 1)) * step);
            gaugeRange.Color = calculatedColor;
            step++;
        }
    }

        public static string LerpHueReal(Color start, Color end, float t)
    {
        var startHue = start.GetHue();
        var endHue = end.GetHue();
        var interpolatedHue = Math.Min(Math.Max((startHue + (endHue - startHue) * t), 0f), 360f);
        var rgb = ColorService.ColorFromHSV(interpolatedHue, 1f, 1f);
        return $"#{rgb.R:X2}{rgb.G:X2}{rgb.B:X2}";
    }

        private static Color ColorFromHSV(float hue, float saturation, float value)
    {
        int hi = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(hue / 60)) % 6;
        double f = hue / 60 - Math.Floor(hue / 60);

        value = value * 255;
        int v = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        int p = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - saturation));
        int q = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - f * saturation));
        int t = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - (1 - f) * saturation));

        if (hi == 0)
            return Color.FromArgb(255, v, t, p);
        else if (hi == 1)
            return Color.FromArgb(255, q, v, p);
        else if (hi == 2)
            return Color.FromArgb(255, p, v, t);
        else if (hi == 3)
            return Color.FromArgb(255, p, q, v);
        else if (hi == 4)
            return Color.FromArgb(255, t, p, v);
        else
            return Color.FromArgb(255, v, p, q);
    }
```